# Is it better to keep the database connection opened in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 application with no ORM. I've created my own queries in the Repository classes. The database is Oracle, but I think this is not important.

I'm opening and closing the database connection each time it is accessed for get/put information but a co-worker has told me that nowadays is more usual to keep the connection opened during the session. Is this correct? Am I doing this wrong?

And in that case, how should I keep the connection open?

Thanks.

Comment: No. Rely on Connection Pooling. This is handled by the database adapter already (at least for SQL Server, I would hope similar for Oracle). The connection itself should only be 'open' over the relevant atomic transactions (which *could* spawn the entire request in some cases).

Comment: `coworker tell me that nowadays is more usual to keep the connection opened during de session` No, you should not keep the connection open, always remember that in general, you shouldn't be holding the resources which you don't want or require at that time. What if 1000 users come to your site, are you going to open 1000 connections and keep them open? It is not at all performance oriented design.

Comment: As @user2864740 said, it means opening/closing connection from .NET is not costly as it sounds. Opening connection is just picking an already opened connection from the pool, and closing connection is just give it back to the pool.